# Android Wear: How to move files from a smartwatch to computer?

Tags: filesystems, wear-os, file-transfer

I need to move some files from a smartwatch to a computer and delete them to free storage.

Before the last update I used Android file transfer but now it doesn't work. I need to navigate the smartwatch file system.

Maybe it's a problem of MTP? I can't find this settings in Android Wear.

Comment: I presume these are files on the so called "external" area that is accessible by all apps? If so, you can simply use "adb" and do "adb pull ..." to get the files from there and then you can do "adb shell" to go there and delete files as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments you can only access files via adb.

Here is a nice and simple tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.droidviews.com/push-pull-files-android-using-adb-commands/)

Answer (score 2):

I created a free app called NavExplorer that easily transfers files over WiFi without needing to enable ADB or type in any commands.

You can get it here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turndapage.navexplorer

Comment: No. The app is not open source at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with nav explorer that it is not access the phone storage card (sd card).